# Ethereum wallet accounts all use same password though I made different ones?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

(tech level, beginner)

installed wallet version win64-0-11-1

deployed a contract, made a token using the example code on ethereum site.

had two accounts in the wallet.  used main account to send to second and test coin.  all worked fine.

when i went to send from second account to a third, kept getting "wrong password" message.   impossible.

made another account, typed the password out on a wordpad and saved it.   copy and pasted it so no typos possible.

it was a password that utilized upper and lower case letters, numbers, and special characters.

i tried pasting the password entirely and tried pasting whatever was prior to first special character just in case.  same results.

all this time, the first password worked for first account.  I said what the heck and tried it in other accounts.  they work.

why is my first password authorizing my other accounts, all of which i specifically made unique passwords for?

Thanks